# free.sprinthost и его ssh

Tags: ssh, hosting

Взял бесплатный хостинг от sprinthost, и хочу подключиться по ssh. Сделал как по инструкции, открыл `Putty` (он уже у меня раньше стоял), вписал ip сервера, и в открытое окно вписал логин и пароль который пришёл мне не почту. Но окно просто закрылось, а если я вписываю не верный пароль то он выдаёт обычное Denied. Пытался менять пароль, но не выходит открыть доступ по ssh. Может потому что у меня бесплатный тариф, а может и нет, не знаю. Почему такое может происходить?
Извините что пишу сюда, просто там нет тех. поддержки для бесплатных тарифов.
Благодарю за любой ответ и коммент! Заранее спасибо

Comment: поищите информацию на самом хостинге, есть ли для бесплатного хостинга доступ или нет. И пишите в тех поддержку хостинга лучше, а не сюда.

Comment: Я указал что у меня нет доступа к тех. поддержке, а на сайте не указано про доступ ssh к бесплатному хостингу

Comment: у них на сайте есть ссылка на  телеграмм бота тех поддержки.

Comment: зарегистрировался для проверки. в письме упомянут лишь доступ по протоколу ftp. протокол ssh не упомянут. ну, раз у вас получалось подключаться, тоже подключился. увы, у них там «заглушка»: ssh-сессия тут же закрывается, выдав сообщение «This account is currently not available.». // резюме: хотите ssh — платите деньги.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поддержки SSH нет в бесплатном варианте.